# Set value in a lookup column during "Create List Item" workflow action

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

Here's the scenario, using SharePoint Designer 2007 and two simple lists in MOSS SP2:

1. I create items in a list called "Code Snippets" with columns Title, Code and Author's CustID
2. I track how many other customers use each snippet in a list called "Snippet Usage" with columns Title (CustID) and Snippet (lookup to Code Snippets, Title column)
3. So as not to duplicate effort, I want to use workflow to capture the usage instance for the original author rather than make a manual entry in the tracking list
4. I set an "on create" workflow on Code Snippets that creates a list item in Snippet Usage, no conditions and one action, "Create list item"
5. In "Create list item" I set the CustID in the tracking list to Author's CustID but here's where it breaks down; when I try to set the Snippet lookup value, Title from the current item isn't available. In fact, the only columns available are ID, Item Type, Level, Path, UI Version and URL. Tried setting workflow variables as well but they're not available for selection either.

What am I missing?

Thanks (as always) in advance!

-Eric

Answer (score 4):

I searched all over the internet for an answer to this exact question.  Finally after happening on a white paper about lookups I found my answer.  I am not sure if this is your problem as well.
When creating new columns in my child list (in my sharepoint site), I had incorrectly made their classification "lookup" instead of "choice", "text", or "number".  I didn't understand that lookup refers only to one column in your list which is utilized to lookup and thus match any other items you are searching for.
Hope this helps someone, I searched for 5 days for the answer.